# Accessing NSString property 'stdString' using the class property list causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos

Getting the crash while accessing the NSString class property(stdString) using the class property lost.

[image: Below image contains the details of crash.]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are invoking a key value coding method (valueForKey:) on a private property, whose value is not managed by the obj-c runtime (seems to be linked to c++ std::string representation of NSString)

Accessing private properties is not a good practice as they can change without notice (to say the least).

I am not sure what is your goal, but if I were in your place, I would try to limit my task such that only public properties are used.